# Add Docker Support is missing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio Community 2017 (v. 15.3.4), Docker for Windows CE (stable channel, v. 17.06.2-ce-win27(13194)) and .NET Core SDK 2.0.0 installed on my PC.
Also, I have enabled Windows Feature called Containers and checked Visual Studio Installer Containers support.

[image]

First I start Docker for Windows (Linux Containers), then I start Visual Studio. I go File -> New -> Project -> Installed/Visual C#/Web -> ASP.NET Core Web Application and hit OK.

[image]

I can't find option to Add Docker Support? Same is if I create project and right click on project, context menu don't give me that option. What am I missing?

Comment: Try installing this https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core to get .net 2.0 on your computer

Comment: I already have .net core 2.0, see first image, powershell

Comment: did you try repairing vs 2017?

Comment: Well, that worked :D thanks!

Comment: 3.2gb later and the repair worked for me as well

Comment: The repair didn't work for me unfortunately. Last week, adding Docker support wasn't an issue..